# SQL statement involving two tables

Tags: python, mysql

I have two tables, sensor and sensor_desc. I want to retrieve sensor.date and sensor_desc.location from both tables where the sensor_id is last inserted.

I've tried this code which doesn't work.

```
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("Select sensor_id from sensor order by date desc limit 1")
        con.commit()
        last= cur.fetchall()
        print '%s' %last
        cur1= con.cursor()
        cur.execute("Select sensor.date, sensor_desc.location from sensor, sensor_desc where sensor.sensor_id= %s AND sensor_desc.sensor_id=%s",(last, last))
        con.commit()
        lastseen = cur1.fetchall()
         print '%s'%lastseen
```

sensor

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| sensor_id | date                | value |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| 12345     | 2015-08-17 10:16:41 | NULL  |
| 12345     | 2015-08-17 10:17:29 | NULL  |
| 12345     | 2015-08-17 10:18:06 | NULL  |
| 12345     | 2015-08-17 13:28:55 |   1   |
| 12345     | 2015-08-17 13:29:49 |   1   |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
```

sensor_desc

```
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+
| sensor_id | description        | location    |
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+
| 12341     | Motion Sensor      | Kitchen     |
| 12342     | Motion Sensor      | Toilet      |
| 12343     | Motion Sensor      | Living Room |
| 12344     | Motion Sensor      | BedRoom     |
| 12345     | Panic Button       | NULL        |
| 12346     | Temperature Sensor | NULL        |
| 12347     | CO2 Sensor         | NULL        |
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd416/1)

Comment: How doesn't it work? What do you expect as result? What do you get as result now? Please edit the question and add this information.

Comment: Please tag with the language you are using.  My thoughts now are that you need to JOIN the two tables together, ORDER BY the sensor_id in descending order, and then limit to one record.

Comment: @Tyra, please stop deleting your other questions.  I was preparing an answer for the one on storing an XBee address in a database table but you deleted it (twice!) before I could submit it.

Comment: Oh! I'm so sorry! I will undelete it, but i was gonna ask something else also related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that combining your two queries gets this:

```
select sensor.date, sensor_desc.location
from sensor, sensor_desc
where sensor.sensor_id = sensor_desc.sensor_id
order by sensor.date desc
limit 1
```

A lot of people on here would prefer that you use the `inner join` syntax but I wanted to highlight how close you already were to something that worked.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL statement you should run should join between the two tables, order by the date, then grab only the first record.

I use `INNER JOIN` here just because you can then omit the `WHERE` clause this way (I feel like it's more readable).

```
SELECT sensor.date, sensor_desc.location 
FROM sensor 
    INNER JOIN sensor_desc ON sensor.sensor_id = sensor_desc.sensor_id
ORDER BY sensor.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```